# Чьи-то пороки (-) для кого-то уроки

Tags: пунктуация

Чьи-то пороки для кого-то уроки.

Answer (score 4):

> Чьи-то пороки (—) для кого-то уроки.

По основному правилу тире не требуется. См. [ПАС, §15:](http://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/#id-3%D0%A2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%C2%A715)

> Тире между подлежащим и именным сказуемым не ставится:
>
> <...>
>
> 6. Если между подлежащим и сказуемым-существительным стоит вводное слово, обстоятельство или **дополнение**, а также союз или частица:
>
> <…>
>
> *Мой отец **для меня** друг и наставник.*

Но как интонационный знак тире в рассматриваемом предложении после слова ***пороки*** может быть поставлено.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Slava, а информация об интонационном тире при наличии дополнения есть у Розенталя или Лопатина, мне ее не удалось найти.

Comment: _Sibylla: "а информация об интонационном тире при наличии дополнения есть у Розенталя?.._ === У Розенталя есть это: _**"Тире, называемое интонационным, может отделять любую часть предложения..."**_

Comment: Может в общем случае, но тогда  вся тема будет выглядеть неопределенной: если по правилу тире не ставится, то можно  его поставить и сказать, что оно интонационное. А вот Розенталь в конкретных разделах этой темы объясняет, почему мы выбираем интонационное тире, например:  "Тире не ставится, если между подлежащим и сказуемым стоят сравнительные союзы как, будто и др.Отступления от этого правила связаны с желанием автора подчеркнуть оттенок сравнения, содержащийся в сказуемом, например: Твои речи – будто острый нож.  Но  про дополнение он ничего не говорит и примеров не приводит.

Answer (score 1):

**Чьи-то пороки – для кого-то уроки.**

Думаю, что тире здесь не авторский,  а обязательный знак.

**Пояснение**

Если дополнение или обстоятельство входят в состав  подлежащего или сказуемого, то **пауза делается и тире ставится** (в этом случае тире определяет  состав подлежащего и сказуемого): Дождь летом – одно удовольствие. Минута с ней – небесный рай. Самая лучшая защита для меня – ясное спокойствие души.

**Сравним:**

1) Мой отец для меня друг и наставник. Варианты: (1) Мой отец для меня – друг и наставник. (2)Мой отец – для меня друг и наставник.  Здесь действительно общее дополнение "для меня".

2) Чьи-то пороки для кого-то уроки. Варианты: (1) Чьи-то пороки – для кого-то уроки.   (2) Чьи-то пороки для кого-то – уроки.  Здесь второй вариант выглядит неестественно, поэтому дополнение скорее относится к сказуемому, а не является общим.

Comment: *Если дополнение или обстоятельство входят в состав подлежащего или сказуемого, то пауза делается и тире ставится* - источник  подобного назовете? Особенно насчет **паузы**? slava1947 Вполне обоснованно сослался на ПАС. Хоть и Лопатин, но сказано-то по делу. А вы просто утверждаете как самоочквидное то, что таковы отнюдь не является.

Comment: По поводу ПАУЗЫ. Если почитать эту тему у Розенталя, то все термины, связанные с интонацией, у него присутствуют,   а именно: зависимость постановки тире от паузы, интонационное членение предложения  на  две части и т.д. http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/42.htm. Конкретно источник попробую найти позже, но это точно не мое личное мнение, в том числе приведенные примеры. Кстати, в них тире явно ставится, дополнение общим не является.

Comment: Да вы не по поводу паузы, а про то, что она ***обязательна*** и требует обязательного тире. Прол паузу это и так ясно, что её можно сделать в любом месте, где просматривается период. Но совершенно не обязательно следовать этому "можно"

Comment: Кстати, я не утверждаю,   а только  высказываю свое мнение, ответ начинается со слова "думаю". Я думаю (считаю), что тире обязательно. А Вы считаете, что при наличии дополнения всегда можно ставить или не ставить тире по своему усмотрению?

Comment: Вы думаете, что ***обязательный***.